# dial tcp lookup: no such host issue on docker windows desktop

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I've installed docker on my office windows 10 Pro machine. I'm facing dial tcp lookup issue while trying to pull from the registry.

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host

I've tried many possible solutions from online. But I couldn't figure out the issue. Can someone please help me regarding this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you `ping` and `nslookup` `registry-1.docker.io`? Are you sitting behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue and the below settings worked for me.

set ***proxy address*** as below in docker settings - 
**username:password@proxyAddress:port**

Eg:

[image]

and also I set DNS server as automatic and it is not set to **8.8.8.8**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but this issue was resolved when I changed my WIFI connection.